# How can I be sure that my javaFX application is loading images from a relative path?

Tags: java, image, javafx

I'm unable to load images in my game despite using what I thought was the proper file path in the java image class.

I've multiple file paths and extensions available, and have messed around with the file location as well, the current file structure is:

```
 --src

   -- main.java

   -- images

     -- the image
```

```
Image earth = new Image("file:projectName/images/img.png");
```

I expect it to show up once I launch my game, but it unexpectedly doesn't show up, and the game doesn't crash neither. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Image img = ImageIO.read(new File("images/img.png"); -- it should work

Comment: @arifng It does not convert properly, says cannot convert from bufferedImage to Image class

Comment: Is it work - ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("images/img.png"));

Comment: @arifng same error

Comment: plz check this link: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javafx/javafx_images.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, images should be under the `src/main/resources` folder. Then you should load them as resources

`new Image(this.getClass().getResource("images/img.png").toExternalForm());` or

`new Image("images/img.png")` - the API assumes the image is in the resource path

The path should be relative to the class you use to call `getResource` on.

Loading them from files will brake after assembling your application, which adds resource as part of the jar.

Comment: When I use this I am told that I cannot convert a java.net.URL to javafx.scene.Scene.image . Should I wrap the code you gave in anything?

Comment: getResource gives you correct URL, but then you use the image with it:
new Image(getClass().getResource("resources/icon.gif")); I also updated the answer

Comment: @NeilEstrada The JavaFX [`Image`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) class has no constructor that accepts a `URL`—it expects URLs to be in `String` form. Just call `toString()` or `toExternalForm()` on the `URL` you get from `getResource(...)`. That said, you should be able to simply pass `"images/img.png"` since `Image` interprets scheme-less URLs to be relative to the classpath (if using Jigsaw modules this can be slightly more complicated).

Comment: @Eugene Ryzhikov Thanks so much for your continued help. I am now getting an error that says no suitable constructor found for Image, any clue why this is occuring?

Comment: Also, why do I not need to include resources in the file path?

Comment: It is possible for resources to be external for the application, but more commonly, static resources are packaged together with the it. That means they are part of the jar in a final form, and that is not the same as loading them from the file directly. So even though it may work in IDE - it will not work after deployment

Comment: `src/main/resources` is a Maven convention.  If a different tool is being used to build, the images can be in a different location, as long as the build packages them from there or includes their location in its runtime classpath.  (I’m sure you know this, but I’m adding it for the benefit of Neil and other readers.)

Comment: Now days, Maven convention is what most tools in Java world use I think